# Extracting Elements from Dynamic UI in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have multiple dynamic text elements. The number of elements is determined by a dropdown. I would like to combine each of the dynamic text elements into a list, but am having difficultly.

I have tried creating a separate reactive object to combine the items.

```
server <-  function(input,output) {

  #define number of names and dynamic names
  output$input_ui1<- renderUI({
    num<- as.integer(input$num)
    lapply(1:num,
           function(i) {
             textInput(inputId = paste0("name",i ),
                       label= paste0("Name",i),
                       value= "enter name")

           })
  })

  #Names into list 
  names_list<-NULL  
  reactive({  
    for (i in 1:input$num ) {
      name<- input[[paste0("name",i)]]
      names_list<-c(names_list, name)
    }
  })


  #access first item of  list of names    
  output$test_text<-reactive({ 
    (names_list[1])  
  })

  #access first name    
  output$test_text2<-reactive({ 
    (input[["name1"]])  
  })



}


ui<- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("num","select number of names",choices= seq(1, 10, 1)),
    uiOutput("input_ui1"),
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01", end = "2010-12-31"),
    uiOutput("test_text"),
    uiOutput("test_text2")
  ),
  mainPanel()
))

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I have two test texts in my UI "test_test" and "test_test2". My expectation is that both should display the same thing, but only the second one is displaying the first name as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `reactives` is not right. For more info see the [tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/).

#### Original code

```
#Names into list 
names_list<-NULL  
reactive({  
  for (i in 1:input$num ) {
    name<- input[[paste0("name",i)]]
    names_list<-c(names_list, name)
  }
})
```

Here is what happens:

1. You define `names_list` as `NULL`
2. You define a `reactive` but **it is not assigned to any objects**, so you can't access it. `names_list` is just a non-reactive object with the value of `NULL`.

Also this part is really weird:

```
#access first item of  list of names    
output$test_text<-reactive({ 
  (names_list[1])  
})
```

`test_text` is a `uiOutput` so you should use `renderUI`.

#### Replacement code:

Assign the reactive to `names_list`, then access it via `names_list()`

```
# Names into list 
names_list <- reactive({  
  lapply(1:input$num, function(i) {
    input[[paste0("name",i)]]
  })
})

#access first item of  list of names    
output$test_text <- renderUI( {
  names_list()[[1]]
})
```